# How to update react es6 component after response from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am new to react and es6 and trying to create search field which fetch some data on type if user type minimum 3 chars on field its make ajax call using fetch api but I am not getting json data when I am running fetch snippet code in browser console its showing json data. whats wrong I am doing in my code. if I get data then how to populate search list I want to know what is the best way to update the component once received data.  in below code I have created sub component where I have one prop called items I will update the prop through state is this right way to re-render the react component?

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchList from "./searchlist"

class SearchField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {SearchText:null,SearchData:{},KeyState:false, items:[]};
  };
  GetLocationData(){
     fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
           .then( (response) => {
                return response.json() })   
                .then((json) => {
                    return json;
     });
  };
  ChangeHandler(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let isKeyUp = this.state.KeyState,
            SearchFieldLength = e.target.value,
            KeyLength = this.props.KeyRefresh;

        if(!isKeyUp && SearchFieldLength.length > KeyLength){
             let jsonData = this.GetLocationData();
             //this.setState({SearchData:jsonData,KeyState:true})
             console.log(jsonData);
        }
  };
  componentDidMount(){

  };
  render() {
    let PlaceholderText = this.props.PlaceHolderText;

    return (
        <div className="input-text-area">
            <input type="text" placeholder={PlaceholderText} onChange={this.ChangeHandler.bind(this)}  />
            <SearchList items={this.state.items} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `componentDidMount`

```
 componentDidMount {
    this.GetLocationData();
 }
```

You should use `compnentDidMount`and call the `GetLocationData()` from there. You will need to update your `state` in the `GetLocationData()` method which will then call the render method for you automatically.

```
 GetLocationData(){
     fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
           .then( (response) => {
                return response.json() })   
                .then((json) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: json
                    })
                    return json;
     });
  };
```

Comment: Currently I am not passing user typed value in above code but I also need to pass user type text as well so I need to make getLocationData in changeHandler method only? just for asking purpose I am using json placeholder api but that will be filtred data based on user inputs